# Understanding the mathematical relation in the convolution sums

Tags: summation, convolution

I am looking at an example on convolution sums. In the example it states the following:

$$ y[n] = \sum_{k=-\infty }^{n }2^{k} = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty } \left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )^{m-n}$$

The sum for $2^{k}$ happens for n < 0, however I feel I am missing some mathematical steps in between and have not been able to understand how it leads to $\left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )^{m-n}$ . Any clarification on the operation  between these two steps or understanding the relationship is appreciated.

Comment: it’s a re-indexing. Set $k=n-m$ in the first summation. Then, $-\infty<k\leq n$ implies $0\leq m<\infty$. Also, $2^{n-m}=(1/2)^{m-n}$. More directly: if you just write out a few terms of both sides, you’ll see they contain the same terms (eg when $k=0$, the term is $2^n$, while if $m=0$ the term is $(1/2)^{-n}=2^n$. similarly, $k=n-1$ corresponds to $m=1$, etc).

Comment: Another way to establish it is first to convert terms $(\tfrac12)^p$ into $2^{-p}$ in order to have homogeneous expressions, then to factor out $2^{n}$, on both sides,

Answer (score 1):

> Starting with the right-hand side we obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{m-n}
> &=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}2^{n-m}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{m=-n}^{\infty}2^{-m}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{m=-\infty}^n2^m\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use $a^{-p}=\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^p$.
- In (2) we shift the index to start with $m=-n$. To compensate this shift we substitute each occurrence of $m$ with $m+n$ within the scope of the sum.
- In (3) we change the order of summation by substituting $m$ with $-m$.